# how to check whether perl cgi request originates from localhost

Tags: perl, http, cgi

I would like to expose a service written in Perl to localhost HTTP requests. I do not want to modify Apache configuration. How to check whether a Perl CGI HTTP request originates from localhost?

I want for this check to succeed even if this call is made through a virtual host eg. https://www.myserivce.com/hidden/service.pl given that the call is made from inside of www.myserivce.com.

Comment: You haven't explained what problems you ran into when trying to accomplish this. In particular, I don't understand what it is at the moment that's stopping your Perl script from doing this.

Comment: The problem is that remote_addr() sometimes returns "127.0.0.1" and sometimes some other addresses.

Comment: Let's see some examples of these results, and the code that obtains them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code:

```
my $server_addr = inet_ntoa(scalar gethostbyname(hostname() || 'localhost'));
my $call_addr = $query->remote_addr();
die unless $call_addr eq "127.0.0.1" || $call_addr eq $server_addr;
```

I do not think it covers all cases, but seems to work with my setup. If anybody knows a generic solution then please submit it here.

Answer (score 10):

[REMOTE_ADDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.8), but that's a dumb way to do it because you put the authentication logic in the application.

Instead, [bind a stand-alone Web server to local interface only](http://p3rl.org/plackup#ARGUMENTS), thus the operating system's IP/networking stack guarantees that no request from outside can reach the server.

Comment: And what should I check with REMOTE_ADDR ? It returns 127.0.0.1 but sometimes it returns IP of the interface (I do not have control over machine to start a web server)

Comment: Check it against localhost IP addresses (in 127.0.0.0/8 and ::1/128, let [Net::CIDR::Lite](http://p3rl.org/Net::CIDR::Lite) assist you) or the address of the interface. If the test fails, reject the request.

Comment: Doesn't work - I get public 194.xx.xx.xx address, even though the request comes from localhost.

Comment: Yes, I have understood that; also, when you use a hostname which resolves to the IP address of the public interface, that's not really localhost - this word has a specific meaning. Anyway, **the word `or` in my previous comment is indeed the Boolean logical `or`**. Apply this information.

Comment: Your comment is a bit offensive. Could you instead write (code) how to do this in Perl?

Comment: Do you know if the public IP address is likely to change in the future, or can you trust that it is reasonably static?

Comment: The IP address is not static, since the software must work on different servers

Comment: @agsamek: Your demand for code is offensive. Demonstrate a willingness to learn and to gain understanding, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you put in `/etc/hosts` file an entry with `myservice.com` and ip 127.0.0.1 then all the requests from localhost to your site will have the `REMOTE_ADDR` set to 127.0.0.1 .

I am afraid that this is the only way to do it, unless you are making requests to `127.0.0.1/hidden/service.pl` instead of `myservice.com/hidden/service.pl`